# ServiceStack - array inside dictionary deserialized to string

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

I have a `DT0` that has the following property

```cs
public Dictionary<string,object> Parameters {get;set;}
```

Now the challenge I have is that if I add an array to the `Parameters` it will be deserialized into a string. Is there a way of deserializing it properly.

One option I have would be to have a strongly-typed `Parameters` property unfortunate it would not work in my case as I'm striving to make it as dynamic as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to make your DTOs as "dynamic as possible" is poor Service design that pokes a hole in your Service Contract to allow unknown Types that will fail in most serializers, will fail in most [non .NET languages](http://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference), can't be documented in metadata services and are susceptible to [additional security restrictions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#late-bound-object-and-interface-runtime-types).

With that said ServiceStack does support accepting [arbitrary JavaScript or JSON Objects](http://docs.servicestack.net/customize-json-responses#accept-arbitrary-javascript-or-json-objects) if you use a property with the `object` type:

```
[Route("/callback")]
public class Callback : IReturn<CallbackResponse>
{
    public object Payload { get; set; }
}
```

But I've also just extended it to support `Dictionary<string,object>` and `List<object>` in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/3d79b222be001c819928ae2be13894d0b163babc) where it will now use the more [dynamic JSON Serializer](http://docs.servicestack.net/js-utils) for parsing object properties and object collections. This change is available from v5.4.1.

But it still should be used sparingly for reasons above as it makes your Services less interoperable and more susceptible to runtime issues.

Consider using `string` when the property value is unknown and have your Service parse it into the expected type, e.g:

```
Dictionary<string,string> Properties { get; set; }
```

Which is more interoperable and doesn't have the issues that allowing unknown `object` does.